# How would I do something like: INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY.... IF KEY IS NULL INSERT NOT UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

So here's my situation:

I basically have a list of UPCs that I'm sending to an API to convert to Amazon's ASIN format and get the price of the item. The API can return 3 things: 1) a new ASIN i haven't had before and its price , 2) an old ASIN where I can update the price, or 3) it didn't match and it returns NULL.

There are hundreds of thousands of theses UPCs and I'm throttled at about 1000 requests/hr on the API so I timestamp them to rerun the oldest or new UPCs first.

Heres what I have:

A table with a primary key on ogID and a unique key on ASIN, and this statement -->

```
INSERT INTO `m01AmazonMine` (
        `ogID`,
        `UPC`,
        `ASIN`,
        `lowestAmazonPrice`,
        `timestamp`
    ) VALUES (
        NULL, 
        '{$prodId}', 
        '{$ASIN}',  
        {$lowestPrice['newAmazon']},
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        UPC                 =   '{$prodId}', 
        ASIN                =   '{$ASIN}',  
        lowestAmazonPrice   =   {$lowestPrice['newAmazon']},
        `timestamp`         =    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ;
```

The problem is that my 48th entry has an ASIN that is NULL; therefor every other UPC that returns a NULL ASIN just overwrites the 48th NULL entry. BUT I need it to create a new null entry to basically just log that it tried that UPC and it won't try it again until its a week or so old. Any problem solvers out there that can figure this one out?

I know that i could just write a php if statement analyzing the ASIN. If it's null run an insert. if its not null run an insert... on duplicate key update. But I'm looking for a single sql line answer.

Comment: Is this SQL run in a loop?  You could just have a condition which says if ASIN is null, create this other record otherwise run this SQL.  Without your PHP code it's difficult to tell.

Comment: yeah I thought of that too, and YOU'RE TOTALLY RIGHT I could do that. I'm really hoping that I could just get it into a one line mysql query basically. Trying to test the limits of the query i guess.

Comment: Was just going to say I didn't wind up finding an SQL command quite like I wanted but I went back and edited the unique key to UNIQUE(UPC, ASIN) instead of UNIQUE(ASIN). Its tricky to use with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Not quite the perfect behaviors and performance I was hoping for but it gets the job done.